# Update matrix entries in beamer

Tags: beamer, math-mode, matrices, overlays

I'm trying to show row reducing a matrix in a beamer presentation.  I'd like to show successive steps of the row reduction using overlays.  The following is close to what I want to do.  The problem is that the matrix on the right moves once all of the minus signs disappear from the first column, in overlay 4.  I've tried using the methods from section 9.5 of the beamer user guide about "Dynamically Changing Text or Images", but neither `overprint` nor `overlayarea` seem to work correctly in an equation environment.  Any tips would be great!

```
\begin{frame}{Row-echelon form}
  Reduce the following matrix to row-echelon form.
  \[\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 & -1 & 3 \\
    1 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
    -4 & 6 & -7 & 1 \\
    2 & 0 & 1 & 3
  \end{bmatrix}
  \onslide<2->
  \to
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
    \alt<2>{2}{0} & \alt<2>{1}{3} & \alt<2>{-1}{-5} & \alt<2>{3}{1} \\
    \alt<2-3>{-4}{0} & \alt<2-3>{6}{2} & \alt<2-3>{-7}{1} & \alt<2-3>{1}{5} \\
    \alt<2-4>{2}{0} & \alt<2-4>{0}{2} & \alt<2-4>{1}{-3} & \alt<2-4>{3}{1}
  \end{bmatrix}\]
  \action<5>{}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possibility is to use `array` environments with columns of type `p{<length>}`, instead of `bmatrix`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Row-echelon form}
  Reduce the following matrix to row-echelon form.
  \[
\left[
\begin{array}{*{4}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash$}p{1.3em}<{$}}}
    2 & 1 & -1 & 3 \\
    1 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
    -4 & 6 & -7 & 1 \\
    2 & 0 & 1 & 3
  \end{array}
\right]
  \onslide<2->
  \to
\left[
  \begin{array}{*{4}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash$}p{1,3em}<{$}}}
    1 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
    \alt<2>{2}{0} & \alt<2>{1}{3} & \alt<2>{-1}{-5} & \alt<2>{3}{1} \\
    \alt<2-3>{-4}{0} & \alt<2-3>{6}{2} & \alt<2-3>{-7}{1} & \alt<2-3>{1}{5} \\
    \alt<2-4>{2}{0} & \alt<2-4>{0}{2} & \alt<2-4>{1}{-3} & \alt<2-4>{3}{1}
  \end{array}
\right]
\]
  \action<5>{}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @gonzalo-medina.  That looks nice.  I've never used the array package before.

Comment: @SMoore please see my updated answer. I fixed math mode inside the cells.

Comment: I thought it looked a little different.  Couldn't figure out what it was.  Thanks for following up.

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid that the entries move around by measuring the widths of the two alternatives and using the larger of the two widths. For this I use `\mathmakeboxlargestof` from [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7121) of Philippe Goutet.

[image: animated output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newlength{\letterwidth}
\newcommand{\mathmakeboxlargestof}[3]{%
    \setlength{\letterwidth}{\maxof{\widthof{$#1$}}{\widthof{$#2$}}}%
    \mathmakebox[\letterwidth]{\vphantom{#1}\vphantom{#2}#3}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\replace{}
\def\replace<#1>#2#3{%
    \alt<#1>{\mathmakeboxlargestof{#2}{#3}{{#2}}}%
            {\mathmakeboxlargestof{#2}{#3}{{#3}}}%
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Row-echelon form}
  Reduce the following matrix to row-echelon form.
  \[\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 & -1 & 3 \\
    1 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
    -4 & 6 & -7 & 1 \\
    2 & 0 & 1 & 3
  \end{bmatrix}
  \onslide<2->
  \to
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -1 & 2 & 1 \\
    \replace<2>{2}{0} & \replace<2>{1}{3} & \replace<2>{-1}{-5} & \replace<2>{3}{1} \\
    \replace<2-3>{-4}{0} & \replace<2-3>{6}{2} & \replace<2-3>{-7}{1} & \replace<2-3>{1}{5} \\
    \replace<2-4>{2}{0} & \replace<2-4>{0}{2} & \replace<2-4>{1}{-3} & \replace<2-4>{3}{1}
  \end{bmatrix}\]
  \action<5>{}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that I use additional braces `{}` around the entries `#2` and `#3`; otherwise the spacing of the minus signs wouldn't be correct.