# Conditionally emphasise / highlight matrix entries

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles

I would like to successively emphasise / highlight matrix entries as specified in a provided list.  Conceptually I'm hoping that I can change the style of the provided matrix cells on the overlays specified.  The code below draws a box around the specified entries on the appropriate overlays but I would like, instead, to change the cell's style (to color blue, or face bold, or whatever).

Is it even possible to "dynamically" change a cell's style in this way?  It is certainly possible to set a single cell's style on matrix setup.

Many thanks.

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      % \tikzstyle{unseen} = []
      \tikzstyle{seen} = [color=blue!70]
      \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
      nodes in empty cells,
      minimum size=7mm, ampersand replacement=\&, every
      node/.style={font={\large\ttfamily\bfseries}}] {
        1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \\
        0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \\
        0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \\
        0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \\
        0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \\
       };
       \foreach \o/\r/\c in {1/2/1,2/3/1} {
         \draw<\o->[seen] (m-\r-\c.north west) rectangle (m-\r-\c.south east);
       }
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: There's a tikz library that adds overlay-aware styles. I can never remember its name, but it is something like beamer-overlay.

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz

Answer (score 1):

Changing the appearence of a node with the `alt` key from [`aobs-tikz`/`overlay-beamer-styles`](https://ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz) is pretty easy.

Changing the content of a node is also possibly but needs an adjustment to `matrix of nodes`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, overlay-beamer-styles}
\tikzset{
  matrix beamer/.style args={<#1>#2-#3:#4#5}{
    row #2 column #3/.append style={
      every node/.append style={
        alt=<{#1}>{#4}{#5}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  % unseen/.style={},
  seen/.style={blue!70},
  matrix seen/.style args={####1/####2}{% ####‽ Ugh.
    matrix beamer={<####1->####2:{seen}{}}}
]
\matrix (m) [
  matrix of math nodes,
  nodes in empty cells,
  ampersand replacement=\&,
  minimum size=7mm,
  matrix seen/.list={1/2-1, 2/3-1}, % <overlay>/<row>-<column>
  every node/.style={font={\large\ttfamily\bfseries}}
] {
1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \\
0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \\
0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \\
0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \& 1 \& 1 \& 0 \\
0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 1 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best solved outside of TikZ's matrix.  Using beamer's `\alt` in an `array` environment as shown [Update matrix entries in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118190/update-matrix-entries-in-beamer?rq=1) is a simpler and more appropriate solution I'm now thinking.

Comment: Since this is only a partial answer, it would probably have been better to add this as a comment.